# chrome indexed database setVersion request filled with exceptions

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I am trying to get the following code to work on chrom by using setVersion (as onupgradeneeded is not available yet).

The IDBVersionChangeRequest is filled with IDBDatabaseException. And the onsuccess function could not be called. I need to create an ObjectStore within the onsuccess function.

specifically this line: **request = browserDatabase._db.setVersion(browserDatabase._dbVersion.toString());**

Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```js
browserDatabase._db = null;
browserDatabase._dbVersion = 4;
browserDatabase._dbName = "mediaStorageDB";
browserDatabase._storeName = "myStore";

var request = indexedDB.open(browserDatabase._dbName);

// database exist
request.onsuccess = function(e) 
{
    browserDatabase._db = e.target.result;

    // this is specifically for chrome, because it does not support onupgradeneeded
    if (browserDatabase._dbVersion != browserDatabase._db.version)
    {
        request = browserDatabase._db.setVersion(browserDatabase._dbVersion.toString());

        request.onerror = function(e) { alert("error") };

        request.onblocked = function(e)
        {
           b = 11;  // for some reason the code goes here...
        }

        request.onsuccess = function(e)
        {
            browserDatabase._db.createObjectStore(browserDatabase._storeName, {autoIncrement: true});
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give me some more information about the IDBException you get?

Answer (score 2):

In your code sample you say you come in to the onblocked callback. The only way you can get in this callback is when you have still open transactions/connections to your db. (aside the one you are working in.) This means you will have to close all other transactions/connections before you can call the setVersion.

Answer (score 0):

When wired things happen to IndexedDB, I "Clear data from hosted apps", quit Chrome windows and take a cup of coffee. After that everything work fine. :-D

`browserDatabase._dbVersion < browserDatabase._db.version`. Downgrading is not possible. `dbVersion = 4` should not be consider lightly. You might open other tab with `dbVersion = 5`, or browser may be waining your response elsewhere or itself updating. All these are not worth to trace the reasons behind.

Comment: Really! Then, that is a problem of old spec.

Comment: I have build a wrapper for indexeddb. When chrome didn't implement the deleteDatabase function yet, I set the version of the db to -1 and cleared all of it's content as workaround. Also the setVersion used a string value, so it would be hard to check if a version increased. Certainly when you didn't need to enter a number

Comment: What i see problem is, if down grading is allowed, once connection try to update, while other connection try to downgrade and become a loop. This situation is possible if use update in one tab, while running old version in other tab.

Comment: Didn't try that out, but in my lib that isn't possible. If you try to downgrade I will give the message myself :). I gave it -1 to be sure the next time they want to create the database the number could be 0. (because it is higher than -1 they wouldn't get an error :))